# Setting the group policy without the console in Windows 7 Home Premium

Tags: windows-7, console, group-policy

I am trying to suppress the prompt that Windows Update provides after an update.  All of the permanent solutions that I have found use the group policy management console to adjust the settings.  I'm not asking about the procedure for that, as there are plenty of questions that address that issue.

The issue is, it seems as though the GPMC is only available for Windows 7 Professional, Ultimate, and Enterprise editions.  Is there any equivalent program/administrator tool/plugin for Home Premium that has the same functionality?  I've just read about the `cmdlets` for PowerShell, but these, too, seem to require the GPMC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search the Policy Tree at http://gps.cloudapp.net/ under Windows Components > Windows Update for something relevant.
I'm not sure which prompt you mean. I gather that most of these policies are controlled by Registry entries.

Comment: That's an excellent site.  I meant the window in the bottom right corner that prompts you to restart or postpone (giving a dropdown with the 10 minutes, ... , 4 hours).  It looks like I may be able to delay that quite a bit (I already had the `NoAutoRebootWithLoggedOnUsers` set).